# how to make login a user in my php web application if rest api response is ok

Tags: php, ajax, api, authentication

I am making a php web application which is interacting with server through rest api 
I am confused that if a user enters correct login credentials then how then what response should be returned with rest api and how I use this response to login user into my application by setting sessions and cookies. 
I can't store anything on rest api server side becauese it is stateless.
then how I validate which user logged in and how I make it secure on client side.

Comment: Would you mind giving us a specified question on your exact problem and maybe also give us some codes. This is WAY to broad

Comment: You may want to take a look at OAuth imlpementation in PHP, here's a starting point : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.oauth.php

Comment: it is the exact problem of my application @Tomm

Comment: basically you can do this however you like, there's nothing which says what your response "should" be (hence why the question is too vague / broad). But making your own authentication system is complex and fraught with risk. Far better to use something pre-built from a respectable source, there are lots of free plugins, tutorials etc out there.

Comment: will you please suggest any free plugin for php @ADyson

Comment: you can easily find something on google to suit your particular situation. I'm probably no bettter at typing "PHP auth system" into a search engine than you are, and you understand your system's requirements in detail, whereas I don't. So it's not helpful for me to recommend anything specific, and besides if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, that kind of advice is considered off-topic.

Comment: I am just making a small project for management of hostel students. which will manage students mess bills, notice boards updates, room allotements